# Problems with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with localstorage, and I have the following snippet, and I wonder why it won't do anything.

```
    var tuotteita = localStorage.getItem("simpleCart_items");
    if(tuotteita != NULL){
    alert(tuotteita);
    }
```

It looks fine to me?

Comment: `ReferenceError: NULL is not defined`

Comment: @aziz.punjani in other words...?

Comment: js is case sensitive use `null`

Comment: Oh... Seems like I mixed it with php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use null instead of NULL (lowercase)

Comment: techincally `lowercase` `small caps` is a whole different thing.